# c++ overloading assignment operator of another class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

i have a c++ class to handle fractions and i want it to allow conversion to double,
i have something like that :

```
class fraction  
{  
    double n,d;  
public:  
    fraction(double _n, double _d) {n = _n; d = _d;}  
    //some functions  
    double todouble() {return n/d;}  
};  

fraction frac(1,2);  
double dbl = frac.todouble();
```

which works fine, but i want to overload the assignment operator so i can go directly with :

```
double dbl = frac;
```

i tried to add this :

```
double double::operator =(double& dbl, fraction& frac) {return dbl = frac.n / frac.d;}
```

which resulted in the following compilation error :

```
 error: ‘double fraction::operator=(double&, fraction&)’ must take exactly one argument
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). The assignment operator can't be overloaded as a stand-alone (non-member) function.

Comment: If you have control of the class, and can modify it, you can make a conversion operator: `operator double() const { return todouble(); }` It must still be a member function though.

Comment: `double` is not a class and does not have members.

Comment: In general, I would advise to shy away from *implicit* conversions. Sure *explicit* conversions (such as `todouble`) are slightly more verbose, but on the other hand they only occur *exactly where you want them*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the ability to assign a `double` to `fraction` you can declare a **non-explicit** constructor:

```
fraction(double d = 0, double n = 1) : d(d), n(n) {}
```

and for reverse

```
operator double() const { return n/d; }
```

and then

```
fraction f;

f = 12.5;      // Assign a double to fraction

double x = f;  // Assign fraction as double to a double
```

Comment: Providing both ways as implicit conversion opportunities will mean that you can use both wherever any of the two types is required, and more, since this makes e.g. implicit conversion from fraction to int possible. This is a dangerous thing to do, as you will get lots of ambiguities and silent conversions that should be errors.

Comment: The constructor signature should be `fraction(double n = 0, double d = 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is conversion operator:

```
operator double() const { return n / d; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot overload an assignment operator as a free function, meaning it must be a class member. Since double is no class, that means you have *no* way to write an assignment afor double.

The only thing that is left is writing a conversion operator for your class:

```
class Fraction {
  //...
public:
  double toDouble() const { return n/d; } 
  operator double() const { return toDouble(); } 
};
```

Having said that, this means you can use a fraction wherever you need a double, int, float, because the compiler uses the operator for implicit conversions, not only to double but also to int and other types that have possible builtin conversion from double. This can be desired for some classes, but it can lead to ambiguities and errors, because one often overlooks the conversion opportuinities the compiler takes into account.

In C++11 there is the possibility to make the operator explicit:

```
  explicit operator double() const { return toDouble(); }
```

This would mean that implicit conversion are not allowed, and copy-initialization won't work, but direct initialization will:

```
 double dbl = frac;  //Error
 double dbl{frac};   //Ok
```

A little **sidenote**: you should make that conversion function const.